# iOS app with persistence. When should I update / sync the model?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, persistence

In my app there are few places where I need persistence - so when data is loaded from server, it is saved. Also I want my model to be synced with data on server.

For example - there is TableView with hundreds of contacts, each of them contains information about other app user, and they can update their profiles any time. So I need to update previously saved data ASAP.

How can I solve this task more effectively?

Comment: More effectively compare to what, and in which sense "effectively"? I mean let's say you are trying a naive solution like updating all the time (or lets say every minute) and syncing ASAP? What exactly is not working for you in the simplest solution that you need a better one?

Comment: I can store last update time of every record that was loaded, and then compare it to date when such record was saved on device. The problem is that can take more traffic and requests than updating the whole model. Other way is to store last update time to all saved contacts and update them together if the was some change after this date.

Comment: Both approaches sound reasonable. I wouldn't optimize on traffic without getting real numbers like how many records you update in average and how much data size do you have in a single record update and overall.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database/), it allows you to Store and sync data in real time.

You can easily integrate it with your current system in no time.

Comment: sure, for some cases it can help, but unfortunately this projects works on it's own server API